# Proving Boundedness

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

A set S is bounded if every point in S lies inside some circle |z| = R other it is unbound. Without appealing to any limit laws, theorems, or tools from calculus, prove or disprove that the set {$\frac{z}{z^2 + 1}$; z in R} is bounded.

I imagine that it's simple, but I have no clue where to start due to the restrictions. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
Estimate case-wise $\frac{|z|}{z^2+1}$ for $|z|<1$ and $|z|\ge 1$:
$$\frac{|z|}{z^2 + 1} \le \frac{|z|}{z^2} = \frac1{|z|} \stackrel{|z|\ge 1}\le 1$$
And for $|z| < 1$ use $z^2 \ge 0$.
This will give you the bound $S\subset[-1,1]$.
An optimal bound is $[-\frac12, \frac12]$, this can be found using $z^2 \pm 2z + 1 = (1 \pm z)^2 \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: First assume $|z| < 1$ and prove that the set is contained in some bounded interval, say $[-1,1]$. Then assume $|z| \geq 1$ and prove the set is contained in the interval $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Can you prove that $\frac{z}{z^2+1}$ is less than some given number? For instance, it is not too hard to show that it is less than 1/2 (hint: start with $\frac{z}{z^2+1}<1/2$ and cross-multiply).

Comment: Plus $-\frac z{z^2+1} \ge -\frac12$, of course. And you don't get strict inequality (pick $z=1$ for example).

Comment: Thanks; you're right on both accounts!